# Implicit operator isn't called for default of struct in C#

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I'm implementing a C# variant of Haskell's Maybe and came across a weird issue where `null` and `default` has different implication on the value returned from an `implicit` conversion.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Maybe<string> valueDefault = default;
        Maybe<string> valueNull = null;
        Maybe<string> valueFoobar = "foobar";
        Console.WriteLine($"Default: (Some {valueDefault.Some}, None {valueDefault.None}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Null: (Some {valueNull.Some}, None {valueNull.None}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Foobar: (Some {valueFoobar.Some}, None {valueFoobar.None}");
    }
}

public struct Maybe<T>
{
    public T Some { get; private set; }
    public bool None { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>() {
            Some = value,
            None = value == null
        };
    }
}
```

The output being:

> Default: (Some , None False)

> Null: (Some , None True)

> Foobar: (Some foobar, None False)

I was expecting both `valueDefault` and `valueNull` to be equal. But seems that `null` is converted while `default` isn't. I fixed the issue by replacing None with HasSome with a reversed boolean condition, but still the question remains.

Why is null and default treated differently?

Comment: This isn't going to be very useful for value types like `Maybe<int>` as you'll never be able to set that to something with `None` equal to `true`.

Comment: For future reference, you'd likely find the answer by debugging the code and seeing that the implicit operator isn't actually called at `Maybe<string> valueDefault = default;`

Comment: @devNull: judging from the _title_ of the question, I think maybe the OP understands that _"the implicit operator isn't actually called"_? I admit, hard to tell. And of course, if they do understand that, it's not clear why they are surprised about the meaning of `default`. I find it difficult to tell exactly what part of all of this the OP fails to understand. Hopefully there's enough info in the comments and answers that they get what they want, whatever that is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho True, I was trying to find a way to force `default` to call the implicit operator. While I instead should set the appropriate default value of `None` within the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Every type* has a default value, including `Maybe<T>`. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) for a list.

`Maybe<string> valueDefault = default;` will assign the default value of `Maybe<string>` to `valueDefault`. What's the default value of `Maybe<string>`? According to that page, since `Maybe<string>` is a struct, its default value is:

> The value produced by setting all value-type fields to their default values and all reference-type fields to null.

So it's an instance of `Maybe<string>` with `Some` being `null` and `None` being `false`. `false` is the default value of `bool`.

The compiler doesn't try to use the default value of `string`, since that requires a further conversion to `Maybe<string>`. If it *can* just use the default value of `Maybe<string>`, why go the extra trouble, right?

You can force it to though:

```
Maybe<string> valueDefault = default(string);
```

`null`, on the other hand, gets converted to `Maybe<string>` because `null` is not a valid value of `Maybe<string>` (structs can't be null!), so the compiler deduces that you must mean `null as string`, and does the implicit conversion.

---

You might know this already, but you seem to be reinventing [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman right because reference types can just be `null`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, null being deduced to `null as string` by the compiler. However `Nullable<T>` wouldn't fit my purpose since I want to in force null validation inside the struct much in the way that `Option<T>` does it in [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext#option) thus potentially preventing `NullReferenceException` being thrown by the consumer.

Answer (score -1):

`default` *always* fills the memory of the struct with zero bytes. `null` is not a valid value for a value type, so the compiler discovers the implicit `(Maybe<string>)(string)null` cast.

Perhaps you could replace with;

```cs
public struct Maybe<T>
{
    public T Some { get; private set; }
    public bool None => Some == null;
...
```